# Meaning of "get" in a sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, verbs

In these sentences (in a book about human rights) I can't understand the meaning of the word "get":

> Treat a person like a human being and you'll get a human being.
>
> Treat people like human beings and you will get truly human beings.

I guess its meaning is "understand" but I'm not certain; that is, if you look any person before you as a human being, you may understand humans and sympathize with them.

Answer (score 12):

Your guess is reasonable, but I think it is incorrect.  Without more context, I would assume that *"you'll get"* means something like "the outcome will be" -

> "Treat a person like a human being and you'll get a human being."

*Treat a person like a human being, and they will behave like a human being.*

This is not an obscure usage of *get:*

- In jokes: *What do you get if cross a parrot with a centipede?*  (A Walkie Talkie)
- In popular song: *[Work your fingers to the bone, what do you get?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7MBaGjVdaIk)* (Boney fingers)
- In unhelpful observations: *Someone stole your purse?  That's what you get for leaving it on your seat.*

Answer (score 2):

This usage of '[get](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/get#get__9)' is similar to the normal usage meaning 'to obtain or receive', except used to describe an *outcome* that you obtain.

So, alternate phrasings:

> - Treat a person like a human being and you'll receive a human being.
> - Treat a person like a human being and you'll obtain a human being.
> - Treat a person like a human being and the outcome you'll obtain will be a human being.

Any of which would be understood to mean

> Treat a person like a human being and they'll behave like a human being.

as [Adam has already pointed out](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/56967/10238).

---

*Note:* The linked dictionary is British, but I know that 'get' is used this way in America, and I assume every other English speaking country as well. This is just the most applicable definition I could find.